# Iterate over a file

Tags: python, file, text, split, iterator

I want to open a file in Python.
For every line in the file split it with `line.split(" ")`, 
 so it will access the first word.

Then check if the word is equal to a given string "TEST". If this is the case delete the line else just keep it.

I have tried using `readlines()` to read the lines. That worked, but then I couldn't figure out how to delete the entire line.

This is my code so far

```
def delete_client(client):
    f = open("clients.md", "r")
    data = f.readlines()

    f = open("clients.md", "w")
    for line_counter in range(len(data)):
        splitted_line = data[line_counter].strip("\n").split()[0]
        print("\n" + splitted_line)

        if client == splitted_line:
            print("Equal to client")
            f.write("HELLO")
        else:
            print("Not equal to client")

    f.close

delete_client("DELETE_ME")
```

The clients file

```
first 192.168.0.14 Lukas administrator
another text 192.168.0.14 Lukas administrator
DELETE_ME 192.168.0.14 Lukas administrator
fourth 192.168.0.14 Lukas administrator
```

Answer (score 1):

The `else:` block should write the line to the file. And get rid of the line that writes `HELLO` to the file (unless you really want this to replace the deleted lines).

```
        if client == splitted_line:
            print("Equal to client")
        else:
            print("Not equal to client")
            f.write(data[line_counter])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension to create another list which does not contain the rows you want to delete and write those rows back to the original file.

```
def delete_client(client):
  with open('clients.md', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

  lines_to_keep  = [line for line in data if line.split(' ')[0] != client]
  
  with open('clients.md', 'w')as f:
    f.writelines(lines_to_keep)
    
delete_client("DELETE_ME")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simulate your desired behavior using:

```py
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(files=('clients.md'), inplace=True, backup='.old'):
    if not line.startswith('DELETE_ME'):
        print(line, end='')
```

Alternatively the "plain old" way works as well;

```py
with open('clients.md', 'r') as in_file:
    content = in_file.readlines()
    
with open('clients.md', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.writelines(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('DELETE_ME'), content))
```

Also when reading/writing files you should use `with`-blocks to assure that filepointers are opened/closed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
def dc(word):
  with open("text.txt") as f:
    i =  [l for l in f if not l.startswith(word)]
  with open("text.txt", "w") as w:
    print(*i)
    for l in i:
      w.write(l)
  
word = "DELETE_ME"
dc(word)
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/bb2a89454d)